# How to get percentage of boolean value documents in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

If I have a collection of documents in MongoDB that all have a boolean value, is there a simple, single function I can run that will return the percentage of documents for which that value is true?

That is to say, if all of my documents look something like this:

```
{    
    _id: ObjectId("Blahblahblah"),
    someAttr: true,
}
```

and only 43% of the total number of collections have a `true` value for `someAttr`, is there any way of retrieving that 43% figure with a single request, or do I have to make two requests to the DB, one to determine how many are true and one to determine how many are false?

Answer (score 2):

Not a simple one. But you can get a count of all documents and all documents where the field is true with an aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    { $group: {
         _id: 1,
         all_count: { $sum: 1 },
         true_count: { $sum: { $cmp: [ "$someAttr", false ] } }
      }
    }
}]);
```

Converting these counts into a percentage would be possible, but unnecessarily complicated to do with MongoDB itself. I would recommend you to do it on the application layer.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind about the performances you can do it with a single request like this.

```
function getPercentage(callback)
{
  var trues = 0;
  var total = 0;

  var docs = db.collection.find();

  docs.forEach(function(doc) {
     total++;
     if(doc.someAttr)
         trues++;

     if(total == docs.length)
         callback(trues/total * 100);
  });
}
```